# Moving file from docker to local while inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, containers, docker-container

I'm having a python program that stores the output file in local. Now my code is run inside docker container I want to move the generated output file (like output.txt) to my local (outside the docker container)

I know there is a command which transfers files from docker to local:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target

#I tried like this inside docker container but it didn't work
os.system(sudo docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target)
```

But since my program is executing inside docker this doesn't work and I want to push the file to local as the code runs.

If you have any ideas please share them.

Comment: Create a volume between your hosting machine and your docker container,  and from your container, copy this file to that volume. That's the best you can do.

Comment: If the main goal of your process is to read and write files from the host system, would a Python virtual environment make more sense as a way to run it?

Comment: @DavidMaze That's right since I'm working on ec2 servers, deploying it and migrating it becomes tricky so the containers are used in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat container as a Linux system, your question will consider as: how transfer files between two hosts.

Maybe there are some another ways without rerun the container:

- `scp`（recommend） with other options or tools while you need, like `expect` could handle the `ssh`'s **accept** fingerprint or input the **password**, assume *172.17.0.1* is the host's **docker** interface and ssh_port is 22 by default, and the `ssh` progress is listening the `docker` interface such as *0.0.0.0:22*.

```
os.system(sudo scp /file/path/within/container user@172.17.0.1:/host/path/target)
```

- other client–server models, such as `rsync`(client and server), `python SimpleHTTPServer`(server) and `curl` | `python request` | `wget`(client) and so on. But these are not recommend, because the server and client need to deploy.

Comment: Cool. You are welcome, sometime maybe there are not only one way to achieve the goal, choose the suitable way in your case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for code inside a container to directly manipulate anything outside the container. The whole purpose of a container is to isolate it from the host system; breaking this barrier would have grave security consequences, and basically render containers pointless.

What you *can* do is mount a directory from the host inside the container with `-v` (or run `docker cp` from outside the container once you are confident it has succeeded in creating the file successfully; but then how would you communicate this fact to the outside?)

With

```sh
docker run --volume=`pwd`:/app myimage
```

you can

```sh
cp myfile /app
```

inside the container; this will create `./myfile` from within Docker.

Comment: @Omroth Touché; it is not *impossible.* But probably save it for another question.